# How to set two views of viewpager in single screen in react-native

Tags: react-native, viewpagerindicator

I am using rn-viewpager library for viewpager in react native.

I want to get this view:

[image]

but I am getting it like this:

[image]

here please ignore left-side 'SCROLL' text and both arrow,

I am using viewpager where 1 and 2 are different view on scrolling it will change here everything is working good except 1 and 2 is not coming on a single screen like the first image. It's coming like second where onScroll only 2 is coming. Here is my code:

```
 _renderRounds(){
    return(
        <IndicatorViewPager
            style={{flex:1,width:60}}
            onPageSelected={(position) => this.onChangeRound(position)}
        >
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center'}}
                       source={this.state.firstRound}
                />
            </View >

            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.secondRound}
                />
            </View >
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}

                       source={this.state.thirdRound}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',
                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.fourthRound}
                />
            </View>
            <View>
                <Image style={{marginLeft:40,justifyContent:'center',

                    resizeMode:'center' }}
                       source={this.state.fifthRound}
                />

            </View>

        </IndicatorViewPager>


    );

}
```

Thanks for help.